# The use of parentheses for the arguments of trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, notation

I sometimes messed up, argument of some trigonometric function with some other text when solving mathematical problem. So I need to keep those confusing argument inside brackets. Below is my question

Is this equation: 
\begin{align}
e^{x^2-y^2}(\cos2xy + i\sin2xy) \tag 1
\end{align}
is same as:
\begin{align}
e^{x^2-y^2}(\cos(2xy) + i\sin(2xy))\tag 2
\end{align}

Comment: Unfortunately it is considered acceptable to use the first form to represent the second.

Comment: IMHO, we always write $f(x)$ to denote the image of an element by a map.

So, for consistency reasons, I think that it's a good idea to write $\sin(\theta)$ rather than $\sin\theta$.

Not to mention the question of ambiguity that may arise in some cases ...